# Updating API Scopes for running kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am running my application on Google kubernetes cluster in GCP , which is a 5 node cluster , i am unable to stop the VM nodes to update API scopes , is there any way to update ?

Regards
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

You only can define the scope on creation of the cluster.

Unless it is absolutely imposible, I would recommend you to delete the old cluster and create a new one with the right scopes.

Comment: Hi Luca   Thanks for the reply , while i add a new 5 nodes and new pool will my old application will be assigned new IP and end points ?